# iOS 9 use UIFont(name: ".SFUIText) found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I use this code and build in ios9 device and crash.
Have any idea to fix it?
Thanks.

```
let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", size: 12)!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to hardcode name of the system font, which is not documented and can change. Use the system font directly:

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

Comment: So, .SFUIText is the same systemFont ?

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr The system font is San Francisco since iOS 9.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Enclose the font name with quotation.

```
label.font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", size: 12)
```